# How to incorporate multiprocessing in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, multiprocessing

I am trying to scrape:
https://www.jny.com/collections/bottoms

In order to crawl and scrape multiple pages at once, I am using multiprocessing

```
 def parse(self, response):
    p = Pool(10)  # Pool tells how many at a time
    print("in herre")
    self.product_url = response.xpath('//div[@class = "collection-grid js-filter-grid"]//a/@href').getall()
    print(self.product_url)

    records = p.map(self.load_url, self.product_url)
    p.terminate()
    p.join()
```

It gives the following error:

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'Crawler.__init__.<locals>.<lambda>'
```

Other answers to this question state that pool should be stated at the start of module. However, that is not possible in this case as `startRequest` is the first method that is called.

Comment: `scrapy` should already handle parallelization of requests internally (by using `twisted`). I think starting `multiprocessing` in `parse` will be a problem. But of course you could start multiple scrapy processes and pass them an option (`-s` I think, or `-a`) and then use this option in `parse` to know which of the processes was started.

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy already scrapes multiple pages at once using asynchronous programming.

You can tune [`CONCURRENT_` settings](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests) to fit your concurrency requirements.